# slow performance of join in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

My recent experience seems to point out that BigQuery with join performs much slower than that with only one table. Normally most queries will finish in no more than a few minutes. But the following join query takes more than 6000 seconds to finish with table1 having ~ 1 billion rows and table2 ~ 1 million rows.

```
SELECT a.*, coalesce(b.field4, a.field3) 
FROM `table1` a left outer join `table2` b
on a.field1 = b.field1 and a.field2 = b.field2
```

Just want to ask the community if this is expected or need further investigation?

Comment: Did you check the query plan using the "Explanation" tab? It shows where the time went.

Comment: yes, actually the bulk of the time went to `Compute` part of the last stage (Stage5)     `READ  
$80, $81, $82, $83, $84, ...
FROM __SHUFFLE0
WRITE  
$80, $81, $82, $83, $84, ...
TO __output`

Comment: How many rows are being written as output? Can you maybe include a screenshot of the slow stage (or all of them) from the explanation in your question?

Comment: sure, just added to my post

Comment: It does seem like the query shouldn't take as long to read/write a billion rows. You could try [submitting a bug report to the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with a sample job ID to have someone from the BigQuery team take a look.

Comment: sure, just submitted one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to specify a destination table. This will take down the total time to less than 200 seconds.